# Stacked bar plot with multiple data and respective data points as legend

Tags: jquery, d3.js, charts

I am trying to create a stacked bar plot. Where each label on x has different data points that are stacked. Some data points overlap across the x-axis and some are unique for only particular label.
I attempted in fusion charts(http://jsfiddle.net/fu2pprmk/) and d3 js. The closest I came across in d3.js ( http://jsfiddle.net/wz1cwrLL/)
When I tried to implement it with missing data points for I get an error

> Error:  attribute y: Expected length, "NaN".
>
> Error:  attribute height: Expected length, "NaN".

Looks like I need to accommodate a check for the missing values. Have no idea at all about d3js. Any input is helpful.

My data example is in this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/wz1cwrLL/1/

Alternatively, can this be achieved in `rCharts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of items stacked on the Y axis for the year 2007 not consistent with the rest of the years. Here is a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mwvhhe3o/

In the simplest form as shown in your fiddle, each object in the data array must have the same number of members.

```
{ year: "2006", redDelicious: "0", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "9", pears: "6",  melons:"0", plum:"0", grapes:"0", cherries:"0" }
```

You can't have the following

```
{ year: "2006", redDelicious: "0", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "9", pears: "6",  melons:"0", plum:"0", grapes:"0", cherries:"0" }
```

So applying the same principle to your example of data here is how I would do it.

```
var data =  [                                           
{   Gene: "KRAS", Leu858Arg: 0, Thr790Met: 0,Gly12Cys: 17, Gly12Val: 12, Gly12Asp: 9, Gly13Asp: 5, Val600Glu: 0 , Arg273His: 0, His1047Arg: 0, Glu69: 0}
{   Gene: "BRAF", Leu858Arg: 0, Thr790Met: 0, Gly12Cys: 0, Gly12Val: 0, Gly12Asp: 0, Gly13Asp: 0, Val600Glu: 13 , Arg273His: 0, His1047Arg: 0, Glu69: 0 }
{   Gene: "EGFR", Leu858Arg: 8, Thr790Met: 5,Gly12Cys: 0, Gly12Val: 0, Gly12Asp: 0, Gly13Asp: 0, Val600Glu: 0 , Arg273His: 0, His1047Arg: 0, Glu69: 0   }
{   Gene: "TP53", Leu858Arg: 0, Thr790Met: 0,Gly12Cys: 0, Gly12Val: 0, Gly12Asp: 0, Gly13Asp: 0, Val600Glu: 0 , Arg273His: 6 , His1047Arg: 0, Glu69: 0  }
{   Gene: "PIK3CA", Leu858Arg: 0, Thr790Met: 0,Gly12Cys: 0, Gly12Val: 0, Gly12Asp: 0, Gly13Asp: 0, Val600Glu: 0 , Arg273His: 0, His1047Arg: 4 , Glu69: 0    }
{   Gene: "CDKN2A", Leu858Arg: 0, Thr790Met: 0,Gly12Cys: 0, Gly12Val: 0, Gly12Asp: 0, Gly13Asp: 0, Val600Glu: 0, Arg273His: 0, His1047Arg: 0, Glu69: 4  }
];
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The fiddle provided above using FusionCharts "stackedcolumn2d" chart, is having the "color" attribute defined in the individual data objects, which is used to set the data plot colors.

**Each Legend represents each dataset series**. So the color that is set for the series will be reflected in the legend for that series. For this you need to set the "color" attribute at dataset level.

Please note : **Legends cannot represent individual data plots**.

Please refer to the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/Akash008/dty7dfzk/4/

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
type: 'stackedcolumn2d',
renderAt: 'chart-container',
width: '500',
height: '300',
dataFormat: 'json',
dataSource: {
  "chart": {
    "caption": "Revenue split by product category",
    "subCaption": "For current year",
    "xAxisname": "Quarter",
    "yAxisName": "Revenues (In USD)",
    //"paletteColors": "#FF0000,#00FF00,#0000FF,#FFFF00",
    "showSum": "1",
    "numberPrefix": "$",
    "showLegend": "1",
    "theme": "fint",
    "legendPosition": "right",
    "legendCaption": "food Items",
    "legendScrollBgColor": "#cccccc",
    "legendScrollBarColor": "#999999",
    "plotHighlightEffect": "fadeout",
  },

  "categories": [{
    "category": [{
      "label": "Non-dairy Product"
    }, {
      "label": "Vegetables"
    }, {
      "label": "Fruits"
    }, {
      "label": "Vegetables"
    }]
  }],

  "dataset": [{
    "seriesname": "Food Products",
    "color": "#FF0000",
    "data": [{
      "toolText": "Egg",
      "value": "11000"
    }, {
      "toolText": "Potato",
      "value": "15000"
    }, {
      "toolText": "Apple",
      "value": "13500"
    }, {
      "toolText": "lettuce",
      "value": "15000"
    }]
  }, {
    "seriesname": "Non-Food Products",
    "color": "#00FF00",
    "data": [{
      "toolText": "Meat",
      "value": "11400"
    }, {
      "toolText": "Eggplant",
      "value": "14800"
    }, {
      "toolText": "Oranges",
      "value": "8300"
    }, {
      "toolText": "cilantro",
      "value": "11800"
    }]
  }, {
    "seriesname": "Non-Food Products",
    "color": "#0000FF",
    "data": [{
      "toolText": "Fish",
      "value": "11400"
    }, {
      "toolText": "Carrot",
      "value": "14800"
    }, {
      "toolText": "plums",
      "value": "8300"
    }, {
      "toolText": "Kale",
      "value": "11800"
    }]
  }, {
    "seriesname": "Non-Food Products",
    "color": "#FFFF00",
    "data": [{
      "toolText": "Fish",
      "value": "11400"
    }, {
      "toolText": "Carrot",
      "value": "14800"
    }, {
      "toolText": "plums",
      "value": "8300"
    }, {
      "toolText": "Kale",
      "value": "11800"
    }]
  }],
}
})
    revenueChart.render();
});
```

You can also achieve the same by setting the chart level attribute "paletteColors" to set the colors for all the series at one go. Refer to the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Akash008/dty7dfzk/3/

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
type: 'stackedcolumn2d',
renderAt: 'chart-container',
width: '500',
height: '300',
dataFormat: 'json',
dataSource: {
  "chart": {
    "caption": "Revenue split by product category",
    "subCaption": "For current year",
    "xAxisname": "Quarter",
    "yAxisName": "Revenues (In USD)",
    "paletteColors": "#FF0000,#00FF00,#0000FF,#FFFF00",
    "showSum": "1",
    "numberPrefix": "$",
    "showLegend": "1",
    "theme": "fint",
    "legendPosition": "right",
    "legendCaption": "food Items",
    "legendScrollBgColor": "#cccccc",
    "legendScrollBarColor": "#999999",
    "plotHighlightEffect": "fadeout",
  },

  "categories": [{
    "category": [{
      "label": "Non-dairy Product"
    }, {
      "label": "Vegetables"
    }, {
      "label": "Fruits"
    }, {
      "label": "Vegetables"
    }]
  }],

  "dataset": [{
    "seriesname": "Food Products",
    "data": [{
      "toolText": "Egg",
      "value": "11000"
    }, {
      "toolText": "Potato",
      "value": "15000"
    }, {
      "toolText": "Apple",
      "value": "13500"
    }, {
      "toolText": "lettuce",
      "value": "15000"
    }]
  }, {
    "seriesname": "Non-Food Products",
    "data": [{
      "toolText": "Meat",
      "value": "11400"
    }, {
      "toolText": "Eggplant",
      "value": "14800"
    }, {
      "toolText": "Oranges",
      "value": "8300"
    }, {
      "toolText": "cilantro",
      "value": "11800"
    }]
  }, {
    "seriesname": "Non-Food Products",
    "data": [{
      "toolText": "Fish",
      "value": "11400"
    }, {
      "toolText": "Carrot",
      "value": "14800"
    }, {
      "toolText": "plums",
      "value": "8300"
    }, {
      "toolText": "Kale",
      "value": "11800"
    }]
  }, {
    "seriesname": "Non-Food Products",
    "data": [{
      "toolText": "Fish",
      "value": "11400"
    }, {
      "toolText": "Carrot",
      "value": "14800"
    }, {
      "toolText": "plums",
      "value": "8300"
    }, {
      "toolText": "Kale",
      "value": "11800"
    }]
  }],


}
  })
  revenueChart.render();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there a way to automate setup the color pick? I have 100's of data point, I don't want to manually add color to each.